# Why does importStatic Eclipse template variable need a namespace?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, import

I'm trying to use Eclipse templates (in Juno) to generate statements for both regular and static imports and ran into something odd.

After consulting the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm) my first attempt was this

```
${:import(org.junit.Test)}                //ok
${:importStatic('org.junit.Assert.*')}    //gives error
```

`:import` works fine, but `:importStatic` gives this error

> Template variable '' has incompatible types

But the syntax above is exactly how it's presented in the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm), where `:importStatic` is identical to `:import` in the left-hand column.

I noticed the example in the right-hand column, which uses a namespace `is` in front of `:importStatic`

```
${is:importStatic(...
```

So I added that namespace, the error went away, and the template works

However I'm a little bugged by this magical unexplained `is` namespace - I can't find any explanation in the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm) of where it comes from. In fact, playing around a little it seems there's nothing special about `is` at all - turns out *any* namespace in front of `:importStatic` will work.

```
${donkey:importStatic(...     //works fine...
```

**So, does anyone know why a namespace is necessary for** `:importStatic` **but not** `:import`**?**

Is the error and the fact it won't save without a namespace just a bug in the template editor or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a namespace, it is an id for the variable used in the template - except that `import` and `importStatic` should not need a variable.

I believe what you are see is [Eclipse bug 336989](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336989) where leaving out the id on **two** statements causes this problem. As you have found the workaround is to specify an id even though it is not required.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that looks like the problem - I tried `something:import` and now `:staticImport` works. Just one question (I'm completely new to this templating stuff) why would a variable need an id anyway? Is it so you can reuse it elsewhere in the template without having to retype the whole statement?

Comment: The id is shown in the initial code generated and should indicate what sort of value is required (`iterable_value` for example). You then tab through these ids providing actual value.